# Translate Laravel Spark plan features

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-spark, laravel-localization

I was wondering what would be the best way to display my Spark plan features in multiple different languages.

Let's say I have the followings features

```
Spark::plan('Premium', 'monthly-artist-premium')
        ->price(10)
        ->trialDays(14)
        ->features([
            'Online profile', 'Access To More Features',
        ]);
```

I thought about doing something like this using Laravel's translation tool and the translation keys

```
Spark::plan('Premium', 'monthly-premium')
        ->price(10)
        ->trialDays(14)
        ->features([
            'base.Online_profile', 'base.Access_to_more_features',
        ]);
```

And then when rendering the plans using Vue I would do something like this, but it's not translating.

```
<li class='pricing-feature' v-for="feature in plan.features">
    @lang('@{{ feature }}')
</li>
```

Any idea how I could implement this to handle multiple languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but here's what I ended up doing:

```
Spark::freePlan('Basic')
        ->features([
            'free_plan'
]);
```

Then when showing the plans in `register-common.blade.php`

I did something like this with the v-if conditions for each different plans

```
<ul v-if="plan.features[0] === 'free_plan'" class='pricing-feature-list'>
    <li class="pricing-feature">
        @lang('base.Online_profile')
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

On Laravel Spark 7.0, I've managed to translate the Feature List by:

1. Appending the translated keys to the language `.json` files.
2. On the `SparkServiceProvider::booted()` method using those keys for the feature list.
3. On `resources/views/vendor/spark/modals/plan-details.blade.php` and `spark/resources/views/modals/plan-details.blade.php`

   ```
   <!-- Modal Body -->
   <div class="modal-body">
       <ul class="plan-feature-list p-0 m-0">
           <li v-for="feature in detailingPlan.features">
               @{{ feature }}
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```

Change to:

```
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="plan-feature-list p-0 m-0">
            <li v-for="feature in detailingPlan.features">
                @{{ __(feature) }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HandleInertiaRequests` middleware to translate the strings before they are shared in the request.

For more info: [Shared data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data)

Sample code:

```php
namespace Application\Http\Middleware;

use Domain\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Inertia\Middleware;

class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Define the props that are shared by default.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        $this->translatePlans();

        ...
    }

    private function translatePlans(): void
    {
        $sparkConfig = config('spark');
        $plans = $sparkConfig['billables']['account']['plans'];
        $translatedPlans = [];

        foreach ($plans as $plan) {
            $plan['short_description'] = __($plan['short_description']);
            $translatedPlans[] = $plan;
        }

        $sparkConfig['billables']['account']['plans'] = $translatedPlans;

        app('config')->set('spark', $sparkConfig);
    }
}
```